# Does View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) forces the view to redraw even if it's already visible?

Tags: android, optimization, view

I'm trying to figure out the optimization for my custom view. I'm wondering if the calling to View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) forces the Android framework to update the view visibility (<- forcing the view to redraw) even if the view is already visible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[No, it doesn't.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/view/View.java)

Take a look at `setVisibility()`:

```
public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
    setFlags(visibility, VISIBILITY_MASK);
    if (mBGDrawable != null) mBGDrawable.setVisible(visibility == VISIBLE, false);
}
```

It simply calls `setFlags()`, which immediately returns if nothing has changed:

```
....
int changed = mViewFlags ^ old;
if (changed == 0) {
    return;
}
```

Even if it(somehow) got past there, it then checks for the individual flags changing, and only updates if one of them is different than it was.

Answer (score 3):

Looking in [`View#setVisibility`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java):

```
public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
    setFlags(visibility, VISIBILITY_MASK);
    if (mBackground != null) mBackground.setVisible(visibility == VISIBLE, false);
}
```

`setFlags(...)` method begins with:

```
int old = mViewFlags;
mViewFlags = (mViewFlags & ~mask) | (flags & mask);

int changed = mViewFlags ^ old;
if (changed == 0) {
    return;
}
```

So I am pretty sure this method doesn't do anything. Otherwise, it would do a lot of things, besides triggering layout and redraw.

[Background#setVisible](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java) is similar:

```
public boolean setVisible(boolean visible, boolean restart) {
    boolean changed = mVisible != visible;
    if (changed) {
        mVisible = visible;
        invalidateSelf();
    }
    return changed;
}
```

the `if` will be false so this will not do anything.

However, `View#setVisible()` is overwritten by: `ImageView`, `MediaRouteButton`, `ProgressBar`, `SurfaceView` and `ViewStub`. You would need to check each implementation if it does anything else extra - you're maybe using one of these subclasses.

Same applies for `Drawable`: there are 8 classes that overwrite `Drawable#setVisible(boolean, boolean)`:

1. ClipDrawable
2. DrawableContainer
3. AnimationDrawable - extends from DrawableContainer
4. InsetDrawable
5. LayerDrawable
6. RotateDrawble
7. ScaleDrawable
8. SlideDrawable

Depending on your combination, you may find that you're actually doing something extra, so you need to investigate what kind of `View` you're using and its background drawable what kind of drawable is it.

Answer (score 2):

setVisibility() sets view flags by calling setFlags inside.. and if we go into sdk  View.setFlags() we can see that this method nothing to do if flags state isn't changed.  Code from sdk View.setFlags() method: `int changed = mViewFlags ^ old;
        if (changed == 0) {
            return;
        }`

Comment: can you post the link to the source code (if available on internet) please?

Comment: for example here [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/view/View.java#View.setFlags%28int%2Cint%29)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% but I don't believe so

from grepcode of the View class, this is from the `setFlags(int flags, int mask)` method which is called from `setVisibility(int visibility)`

```
int changed = mViewFlags ^ old;
if (changed == 0) {
    return;
}
```

after this in the same method are calls to `requestLayout()`and `invalidate()`

so going by that I'd say no it doesn't